# How to use external custom element (plugin) in Aurelia app?

Tags: javascript, aurelia, custom-component

I've defined a custom element in a github repo. I then `jspm install`'d said element in another app.

What is the correct way of importing this element in the other app? When I call `aurelia.use.plugin('aurelia-custom-element')` in the app config, it says that the it can't find `aurelia-custom-element.js`.

aurelia-custom-element.html:

```
<template>
<div>Hello world, from Aurelia custom element!</div>
</template>
```

aurelia-custom-element.js:

```
import {customElement, bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';

@customElement('aurelia-custom-element')
export class AureliaCustomElement {
}
```

index.js:

```
export * from './aurelia-custom-element';

export function configure(config){
  config.globalResources('./aurelia-custom-element');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you put `aurelia.use.plugin('[here]')` should match what you jspm installed.

For example, if the github repo containing your plugin is https://github.com/uavalos/mega-plugin, you would execute `jspm install github:uavalos/mega-plugin` to install the plugin.  To load the plugin you'd write `aurelia.use.plugin('uavalos/mega-plugin')`.

If you share the url of your plugin I could provide more specific help.

Comment: No that didn't do it. I can't share the code because its a private repo, but it is literally the code shown above. I updated `use.plugin` but it still can't find the file

Comment: Actually, I think that may have done the trick. I seem to be having issues w/ the host app

Comment: Nope the app is working fine but it's still not loading plugin

Comment: It was ultimately a couple of things: (1) `use.plugin` needs to match `jspm install`. (2) `package.json` needs a `jspm.directories` section as well as a `jspm.main`. (3) yes, there really was something wrong with host app... don't know what it was but I started from scratch and everything works now